# Как правильно сделать условие на проверку ссылки

Tags: php, if

Ребят у меня такая проверка ссылки, подскажите как сделать условие на окончание

То есть к примеру если у ссылки окончание не gif png jpg то выводить ошибку } echo "это не картина";

---

if (filter_var($banner, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) { 
код

### }else {echo 'Неправельный ввод ссылки банера!';}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<code>
<?php

$link = 'local.host/images.gif';
$subLink = substr($link, -3);

if( 'jpg' == $subLink || 'png' == $subLink || 'gif' == $subLink){

    echo 'Это картинка';
} else{
    echo 'Это НЕ картинка';
}
</code>
```

А вообще откуда Вы получаете картинку? Пользователь сам ее загружает или как?

Comment: да ссылкой на баннер

Comment: `код`
$banner = $_POST['banner'];
$subLink = substr$banner, -3);
if( 'jpg' == $subLink || 'png' == $subLink || 'gif' == $subLink){

    echo 'Это картинка';
} else{
    echo 'Это НЕ картинка';
}

`код`
Получается так?

Comment: Да. Этот вариант должен работать. Только не забывайте за скобки. $subLink = substr($banner, -3)

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, сделал по вашему примеру работает идеально